# How could a tobacco/nicotine prohibition be efficient?

Tags: cities, law-enforcement, criminal-underworld, dictatorship

In *The Dictatrix and the Navigator* (a live-action feature film I am writing, I want to direct myself, and I would like to play some characters within it) (I want to play both the Dictatrix and the Navigator), one of the two protagonists is a dictatrix. She makes a nicotine prohibition, or more accurately, a recreative tobacco prohibition (medical tobacco is fully legal) (medical tobacco means nicotine pills and nicotine gums). What I mean is the anti-villainous Dictatrix prohibits both smoking and chewing tobacco, and she hires many police officers for arresting people who sell recreative tobacco (nicotine addicts are immediately put in rehab). Strangely, the Dictatrix is against torture, and she only uses the death penalty for the vilest people (in other words, politicians who are both opposed to her and cruel even by her standards, cannibalistic murderers, and torturers).

The country of reference in my story is a Dominican Republic pastiche (if Dominican Republic were a city-state).

So, I wonder how could a nicotine/tobacco prohibition be efficient? Also, would banning nicotine be comparable to banning cholesterol?

Comment: I think you're focusing too much on the character in your question, which is irrelevant regarding if people will find a way around the restrictions or not, and a good risk people will close it for being story-based ^^'. [...]

Comment: [...] Meanwhile, I think we need to know what kind of culture and nation we're talking about, like a country of reference, how tobacco is currently perceived or the main political focus of the years before the prohibition (hiring more policemen for instance). That'd give the resources we have access to ensure the law is respected, and the levers we have to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: How are there no cartels in a criminal underworld with chemical dependencies outlawed? I suppose I am most confused by the word “efficient” in the title, but the question seems to want this all to work (effective). Efficient means it uses resources (money) well. This law will definitely raise tax revenue, so “efficient” it is. But it won’t be effective without magic.

Comment: what budget does Dictatress has? what percentage of the population is smoker? Saudi Arabia has this tobacco fatwa and they are strict, but do you want another Saudi Arabia?

Comment: Shouldn't it be _Dictatrix_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Strict import restrictions

While it's true that demand will always create a black market, your goal is to create a *more* effective prohibition. Fortunately, you're on an island nation, and that makes smuggling considerably harder, especially if you have a very effective and militarized Coast Guard. Make it illegal to import tobacco in any form except government shipments of nicotine pills.

### Strict growing restrictions

Ban the growth of tobacco on the island. Tobacco is labor intensive, soil intensive, and fertilizer intensive. It is rarely profitable outside of large industrialized. Small farmers in areas where tobacco farming is legal, like Indonesia, [frequently struggle](https://tobacconomics.org/research/the-economics-of-tobacco-farming-in-indonesia-results-from-two-waves-of-a-farm-level-survey/) to turn a profit.

### Ban tobacco advertising

Part of the reason smoking is so popular is *very* effective marketing. There's no reason to allow that to happen in your country. Ban all advertising related to tobacco.

### Promote alternatives advertisment

Make using nicotine pills (as an alternative to other forms of tobacco) seem cool. Depict it as futuristic, confident, discreet. Show clips of laughing, clean-cut professionals celebrating and partying on a beach, with pill bottles of nicotine. Make smoking be perceived as rude and uncleanly. (That shouldn't be hard. People who don't smoke usually find the smell of cigarette smoke repulsive)

### Import tobacco-specific pests

*Mole Crickets* are a notoriously destructive tobacco pest. They're also a delicacy in the Philippines, and a great source of protein. Establish mole cricket farms that you can use to create plenty of extra nutritious food for your country. High in iron, riboflavin, protein, vitamin B, and other nutrients, and able to feed on things that common livestock turns their nose up at. Naturally, as a side effect of farming them, they will likely become endemic to the island as a minor agricultural pest which is *especially* destructive to tobacco.

As a bonus, Mole crickets are terrible for lawns, and lawns are a degenerate capitalist invention that your pastiche of the Dominican Republic will soundly decry.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, with adequate level of enforcement**

Unlike the use of many other controlled substances, smoking (or chewing) tobacco leaves lingering odor and tooth enamel residue.

If you are willing to crack down on people with addiction (as opposed to just producers and dealers), the issue can be largely kept under control. If everyone is subjected to a quick weekly test that can send anyone to jail just as quick, there won't be many tobacco users left.

Injectable nicotine, if that appears on black market, would be an issue though.

Comment: We already live in a world where users are punished. We've discovered that their addictions (or in some cases, even non-addictive desires) are stronger than fear of punishment. And nicotine is far more addictive even than heroin. This is a fool's errand dreamt up by someone who grew up drowning in too much just-say-no propaganda.

Comment: @John O "their addictions ... are stronger than fear of punishment" - with adequate level of enforcement, the answer is "who cares". As long as all addicts are rounded up in labor camps (or worse), the rest of the society is "clean".

Comment: There is no "adquate level of enforcement" that still resembles a functional society. As you make society hellish enough that you've removed the addicts, other people are drugging up just to numb themselves to the nightmare you've created. This is another one of the myths that drug warrior propaganda pushes... "that if only we really wanted to, we could make it all stop". You can't. When people have 5 minutes during a day not under surveillance, when they have the bodily autonomy that you can't sample their blood constantly, they'll do this.

Answer (score 1):

A prohibition will *always* create a black market.  If there are no tobacco cartels when the prohibition goes into effect, existing organized crime (there's *always* organized crime -- because, contrary to adage, crime *does* pay) will begin to fill the demand.

There were no cartels supplying illegal alcohol in 1918.  There were occasional small time smugglers bypassing taxes (just as there are occasional attempts to smuggle cigarettes from low-tax to high-tax locations -- but by the case, not the tonne), but big organized crime didn't get involved until suddenly *nobody* could legally buy whiskey, wine, or even beer.  Ten years later, these gangs ran whole governments.

Ban non-medicinal tobacco and pretty shortly there will be a thriving business in helping people get past their nicotine fits -- while turning a huge profit (because the price of a cigarette will go up, but the sellers are paying no taxes).

Comment: This is quite probable. However please note that the question is asking about "how to make it as efficient as possible", not "if it will work", so you're not really answering it. Do you have tools to offer to make this prohibition more efficent, albeit not perfect?

Comment: @Tortliena Nothing can be efficient without first being effective. The latter is a requirement for the former.

Comment: @JohnO I'm sorry to say that, but telling that something can either work or not is a black and white, contrived view which not what I or the asker asked for. Even if benefits are marginal, you should have left a "but if you really have to, take -or don't take- example from this", even if it's to make a 0% effective solution to a 1% one. As it is, this answer should have been left as a comment :).

Comment: @Tortliena Efficiency is the condition of achieving a goal more quickly and/or with fewer resources, also implying that the goal can be achieved to an even greater degree (though, they may choose not to do that). If we can assume from your proposed legislation that your goal is for fewer people to use nicotine, and for them to do so less often, then this prohibition is a complete failure from the outset. Nothing can achieve that goal, and since nothing can achieve it, it can't be made more efficient. This isn't a good premise for an interesting story, and you should do some introspection.

Comment: @JohnO You confuse setting a threshold to reach (the goal) and measuring how far you're from reaching it (efficiency). DanielB gave many ideas to prevent tobacco usage. Do you mean that NONE reduce the consumption, even by 0,1%? Do you mean that new consumers are willing to get into smoking, even if they've never smelled it in their entire life? Know that's what you're currently telling.

Comment: @Tortliena Efficiency isn't "how far away you are from reaching your goal". I've never in my life seen the word used in a way that suggests that connotation. I know everyone here isn't English-as-a-first-language, but if that's the case for yourself, I'm informing you that you are wrong. Yes, I am telling you those things, and it's not idle speculation, this experiment is run every day on our planet in massive numbers, and the results are in for anyone willing to turn on their brain and observe them. The sociology of this issue is a settled matter.

Comment: @JohnO [Efficient](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/efficient) : The extent to which a resource, is used for the intended purpose; the ratio of useful work to energy expended. Things are rarely 0 or 1, false or true. not thinking so is making a false dilemna (it works *or* it doesn't forgetting it can be not as effective as it could be). Now, the W.H.O. tells that "[comprehensive bans of tobacco advertising reduces consumption](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/tobacco)", among many other tools. Do you have a proof that all methods make no effect at all ?

Comment: @Tortliena If your intent is to stop people from using tobacco, and none of those people stop using it, you are indeed at a zero. You may imagine in your head that "we're so close to getting them to stop" and that this constitutes some partial success (and some efficiency), but that is your imagination and not true partial success. There is no efficiency there... not just hidden efficiency that you cannot measure because there's no good instrumentation that can do so, but none at all.

Comment: @JohnO That's the contradiction you're having : Not all people stopped, therefore noone stopped. Or without smoking context, not all birds are doves, therefore no bird is a dove. And... That you entirely disregard new, young people who didn't start smoking x). You need to take the time to breathe (hopefully not smoke :p) that in, and think why your mind's so pessimistic about drugs addiction, because so far I only read claims without backed-up proofs ^^'. I'll stop right there, since I've got nothing more interesting to say on this matter.

Comment: @Tortliena That's your drug warrior propaganda kicking in. Virtually no one stopped, those who stopped did so because of reasons personal to them and were going to do it anyway, and the rest just "slowed down". Human behavior isn't modifiable in the way that you want. In the real world that I inhabit, the one not scripted by DEA school programs, nearly 90% of adults in the United States have tried schedule I substances, even though those have never been legal at any point in their lives.